# maven intellij java mapreduce test program

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, greenplum

I have created a maven project in IntelliJ with three class files:

```
package mavenKris;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: kshk
 * Date: 11/27/13
 * Time: 2:27 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class WordMapper extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(key, word);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package mavenKris;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: kshk
 * Date: 11/27/13
 * Time: 2:29 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class AllTranslationsReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String translations = "";
        for (Text val : values) {
            translations += "|" + val.toString();
        }
        result.set(translations);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

and main...

```
package mavenKris;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: kshk
 * Date: 11/27/13
 * Time: 2:30 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Dictionary {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "dictionary");
        job.setJarByClass(Dictionary.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(AllTranslationsReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        boolean result = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.exit(result ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

and this is how the pom.xml looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mavenKris</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenKris</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mavenKris</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anorak-releases</id>
            <url>http://ip-10-40-3-96.cloud.trendinglines.co.uk:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/atlassian/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I am using greenplum distribution of hadoop, now..when i run the above project I get this error....

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7551 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/kshk/IdeaProjects/mavenKris/target/classes:/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at mavenKris.Dictionary.main(Dictionary.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

If i specify the path the class path from commandline it called the Dictionary class but gives error, so there must be some setting on my IDE which is not speciying the class path to hadoop-core at runtime.....

```
[kshk@localhost mavenKris]$ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/kshk/IdeaProjects/mavenKris/target/classes:/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0/hadoop-core-1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:143)
    at mavenKris.Dictionary.main(Dictionary.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
[kshk@localhost mavenKris]$
```

**UPDATE2:**

after adding path to commons-logging-1.0.3.jar..........

```
[kshk@localhost repository]$ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/kshk/IdeaProjects/mavenKris/target/classes:/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0/hadoop-core-1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UgiInstrumentation.create(UgiInstrumentation.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.<init>(JobContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:54)
    at mavenKris.Dictionary.main(Dictionary.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

**UPDATE 3:**

added :/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar to path....

```
[kshk@localhost repository]$ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/kshk/IdeaProjects/mavenKris/target/classes:/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0/hadoop-core-1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricMutableStat.<init>(MetricMutableStat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.<init>(MetricsSystemImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.<init>(MetricsSystemImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UgiInstrumentation.create(UgiInstrumentation.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.<init>(JobContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:54)
    at mavenKris.Dictionary.main(Dictionary.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

**UPDATE 4:**

added :/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar to classpath

```
[kshk@localhost tmp]$ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/home/kshk/IdeaProjects/mavenKris/target/classes:/home/kshk/Software/idea-IC-129.1359/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0/hadoop-core-1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/kshk/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/commons-lang-2.1.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at mavenKris.Dictionary.main(Dictionary.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
[kshk@localhost tmp]$
```

EDIT:

library jars in intellij
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running it from IDE, you should first change your pom to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mavenKris</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenKris</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenKris</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anorak-releases</id>
            <url>http://ip-10-40-3-96.cloud.trendinglines.co.uk:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/atlassian/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-gphd-1.2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I suppose that anorak-releases is local mvn repository and that you have hadoop-core there. Check if it is there since it wasn't working for me, so I had to put :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

instead to get it work.

Right click on the pom file in InteliJ and chose "Synchronize POM" in order to import proper libs. Then start your program from  IDE.

After this command line looks like:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7533
>   -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/opt/instalations/idea-IU-123.169/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/work/eLearning/reactive_scala/hw2/untitled/mavenKris/target/classes:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.0.1/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.14/jetty-6.1.14.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.14/jetty-util-6.1.14.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api-2.5/6.1.14/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/root/.m2/repository/tomcat/jasper-runtime/5.5.12/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/root/.m2/repository/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.12/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.7.1/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/sf/kosmosfs/kfs/0.3/kfs-0.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/opt/instalations/idea-IU-123.169/lib/idea_rt.jar
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain mavenKris.Dictionary
>   dictionary.txt output.txt

Comment: sorry i did not get about the classpath? AFAIK i am executing run from IntelliJ....

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have copied the new pom.xml but i still get the same error....

Comment: Have you "Right click on the pom file in InteliJ and chose "Synchronize POM" in order to import proper libs. Then start your program from IDE."?

Comment: i also used the 0.20.2 hadoop-core verision and after sysnchronzation, still get the same error....looks like at run time it cannot find the classpath..

Comment: It worked for me, but there were some other errors after using 0.20.2. Try to import  hadoop-core.lib manually into your IDE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42141/discussion-between-user987339-and-krisdigitx)

Comment: I've added IDEA start line.

Comment: if i add the pull path to hadoop-core at runtime it calls the Dictionary class properly byt still has errors, I have updated post...

Comment: It seems that you are missing commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.jar, Add it also as you did with hadoop.

Comment: You are missing commons-configuration-x.x.jar. Find it and add it to the path

Comment: Add commons-lang-x.x.x.jar

Comment: cool looks like most of the errors have gone...I think now i am supposed to run the jar file on the hadoop cluster...is that right?

Comment: cool cool :) but why is intellij not able to add the classpath?

Comment: InteliJ added it when I right clocked refresh on pom.xml for me. I don't know why this didn't work for you. you can go to command line and try : mvn idea:idea which should generate idea project from pom, and then import that project.

Comment: deffo :)  i will try importing it again

Comment: mmmm....:) I am running intelliJ on fedora xfc as user account from /home/kshk and maven is installed as root at /opt/apache-maven-3.1.1

Comment: I run it on ubuntu. Try running idea as root.

Comment: I think i figured out the problem with intellij, when I add the jars manually to library path then it works fine...see the image attached in the post, whats annoying me is that intellij is not using paths to jar provided by maven....so this need to be specified manually, so i think there is something wrong with maven integration in intellij on my setup...

Comment: go with "mvn idea:idea" this will create project for idea. then import it. all libs should be there.